# Is Visual Studio's std::mutex implementation incorrect or just "weaker" than other stl implementations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mutex

My understanding of mutex is that it has two guarantees:

- Mutual Exclusion
- Given an n, it will guarantee that a waiting thread will acquire the lock after n other threads have "cut in line".

I know semaphores must have the second guarantee, and I expect that mutex should also have it since all platform dependent mutex apis seems to have it, but I can't find it anywhere in the standard that requires std::mutex to have it.

When I run the following code on my machine, the "erratic" thread is starved by the "consistent" thread.  (compile with no arguments, just cl file.cpp and g++ file.cpp -std=c++11 -o whatever)

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

#define THREAD_COUNT 1 
#define ITERATIONS 1'000'000

uint64_t consistent_counter = 0;
uint64_t erratic_counter = 0;
bool finish = false;
uint64_t sleep_count = 0;

std::mutex mytex;

void erratic()
{
  int i = 1;
  while (!finish)
  {
    if (i % 100 == 0)
    {
      ++sleep_count;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
    ++i;

    mytex.lock();
    ++erratic_counter;
    mytex.unlock();
  }
  finish = true;
}

void consistent()
{
  while (!finish)
  {
    mytex.lock();
    ++consistent_counter;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {

    }

    mytex.unlock();
  }
}

int main(void)
{

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;


  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
  {
    threads.emplace_back(consistent);
  }
  std::thread erratic_useage(erratic);


  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

  finish = true;

  erratic_useage.join();
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
  {
    threads[i].join();
  }

  std::cout << "erratic: " << erratic_counter << std::endl;
  std::cout << "consistent: " << consistent_counter << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sleeps: " << sleep_count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
.\test_g++.exe
erratic: 1400
consistent: 4516
sleeps: 14

.\test_vs.exe
erratic: 1
consistent: 3779
sleeps: 0
```

The "eratic" thread only gets the lock once despite the other thread getting the lock 3779 times.  This violates the second guarantee that I believe mutexes have.

The version reported in the Visual Studio Installer is Visual Studio Enterprise 15.5.4

One suggestion is this is caused by using Microsoft CRITICAL_SECTION, but the critical section documentation ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472(v=vs.85).aspx),[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683476(v=vs.85).aspx)) says "... however, the system will be fair to all threads".  I interpret this as equivalent to the second guarantee.

Another commenter said that there is too much contention on the lock.  That's the entire point, if there were no contention the second guarantee would not be needed.

Zan Lynx's comment may be applicable, since I am running on a (modern) AMD machine, but even then mutex should be high enough level that the OS deals with known hardware features.

Someone said that debug mode "if the original problem doesn't appear in release mode of the example, we cannot say much about it."  This is fundamentally false.  Although this is multithreaded and thus nondeterministic, the result of the program in debug and release (optimizations vs no optimizations) should be consistent.  If it isn't, then the compiler is buggy (sequentially consistent if data race free).  Since all shared variables are protected, there are no data races (consistent_counter and erratic_counter are protected implicitly by the join()).

Comment: Your second guarantee is not provided by `std::mutex`. You may be confusing it with a different kind of mutex.

Comment: What other kind of mutex is there?  Also, I'm trying to determine if vs's mutex is "bad", since g++'s doesn't have this behavior.

Comment: `std:mutex` is pretty much the intersection of various implementations, such as pthreads, Windows, and others.

Comment: Also note that `volatile` does not protect against concurrent modification – `finish`needs to be `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: I can reproduce the `erratic: 1` case only when running in Debug mode. In Release mode I get `erratic: 19001`, which is consistent with it sleeping for half a second 19 times in 10 seconds.

Comment: That's because it is optimizing out the buisy wait, thus changing the workload.  Running my original application in release does not fix the starvation.

Comment: Just saying that any kind of timing tests in debug mode is of little value, as the compiler isn't even *trying* to get that right. The goal is to make single step debugging easier, nothing else. And if the original problem doesn't appear in release mode of the example, we cannot say much about it.

Comment: Standard `volatile` is for accessing memory-mapped hardware ONLY.  VC++ gives `volatile`extra guarantees unless you set some properties value that I forget. Even with the extra guarantees, it is NOT suitable for inter-thread communication.

Comment: In Release mode I get far more "consistent" than "erratic".  Investigating.

Comment: @BoPersson Like I said above, release mode will optimize out the busy waits, thus making the results invalid because it changes the thread load and timings.

Comment: In Debug I get about twice as many erratics as consistents. It's Apples vs. Oranges in any case. Erratic sleeps most of the time. Consistent consistently does nothing. I do not understand what's being tested here.

Comment: @JiveDadson The erratic thread should be getting the lock at least 999 times in ten seconds, while it only gets it once.

Comment: When I run it in Debug, erratic gets about 9000 - 13,000.  G'night.

Comment: I am going to bow out now.  The volatiles are gone, but I want to reiterate, standard `volatile` makes no memory order guarantees. VC++ `volatile` makes some guarantees,  if they are not disabled with a property-setting, but often they are not the right ones. Far better to use std::atomic.

Comment: Y'all should also know that AMD does spin-locks differently from Intel, which may explain some of your different experiences. On AMD hardware because of differences in cache coherency protocols the local core will *always* grab the cache line first if it already had it, leading to one core hogging all the locks if it has the free time.

Comment: Could explain it, as I am on an amd machine, except it doesn't happen with g++.

Comment: side note: never call `lock` on a mutex yourself, let [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) do it for you. Otherwise you risk deadlock

Comment: @Max looking into the CRT source it looks like up to VS2017 `std::mutex` is based on the concurrency runtime which uses the windows critical section implementation as its base. That said the debug behavior IS different than the non Debug behavior.

Comment: I also want to point out that unfair locks are almost always faster and better, because any situation that relies on locking and unlocking so quickly is probably not using a very good multi-processor algorithm. It should be doing much larger chunks of work before needing the lock again.

Comment: The msdn on critical sections ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472(v=vs.85).aspx),[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683476(v=vs.85).aspx)) says:"There is no guarantee about the order that threads obtain ownership of the critical section. However, the system is fair to all threads."
So I don't think you can attribute this to use of critical sections.